# set environment variables in nuxt3 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

Hi I'm using nuxt3 to develop SSR project!
I want to set environment variables to control the API url.
I set it like this in the scripts of package.json.

```
"serve-dev": "set ENV=development && nuxt dev",
"serve-prod": "set ENV=production && nuxt dev",
```

When I console.log the env, I found that the setting is successful.
But the Judgment will log "false".
[image]
[image]
You can find that the first two lines of console.log are correct, but the third line will display an error.

How did this happen.

Comment: are there any trailing whitespaces

Comment: @cmgchess OMG, I remove the whitespaces before the &&, and it works... my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake,
Just remove the whitespaces before the "&&" and it works.